# Serialize object with json.net with nested dictionaries

Tags: c#, json

I'm a little lost with serializing a JSON object, I'm trying to serialize the Item class into a JSON

```cs
class Item
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> components = new Dictionary<string, object> { };
    public string mixins { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

class Components
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> unit_info = new Dictionary<string, object> { };
    public Dictionary<object, object> generateUnitInfo()
    {
        unit_info.Add("bla", "blubb");
        unit_info.Add("blubb", "bla");
        return unit_info;
    }
}
```

My JSON should look like this

```
{
   "components": {
      "unit_info" : {
         "bla": "blubb",
         "blubb": "bla",
      },
   }
}
```

Any hint would be helpful, thanks in advance

EDIT: thats the code that I have so far

```cs
Component c = new Component();
Item item = new Item();
item.type = CBItemType.SelectedItem.ToString();
item.mixins = "test mixins";

item.components.Add(c.unit_info, c.generateUnitInfo());
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, Formatting.Indented);
```

and thats what I get

```
{
  "mixins": "test mixins",
  "type": "entity",
  "components": {
    "(Collection)": {
      "bla": "blubb",
      "blubb": "bla"
    }
  },
  "entity_data": {}
}
```

The generateUnitInfo method adds 2 k/v pairs to the unit_info, I want instead of (Collection) unit_info

Comment: you should use the newtsoft json serializer, the default json serializer has issues with dictionaries

Comment: As mentioned in my title I'm trying to use json.net

Answer (score 1):

You can use anonymous objects ([Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json))

```
var obj = new { components = new { unit_info = new { bla="blubb", blubb="bla" } } };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Built-in *JavaScriptSerializer* would give the same result too

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```

PS: If using dictionary is a must you can use it too

```
var obj = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {
        "components", new Dictionary<string,object>()
        {
            {
                "unit_info" , new Dictionary<string,object>()
                {
                    { "bla", "blubb" }, {"blubb", "bla" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Both serializers will return your expected json.

Comment: What if I want to add more stuff to the components dictionary?

Comment: @vice_versa then add. What is the problem? It is a just a shortcut of an initializing a dictionary. Fill it whichever way you know.

Comment: I think I didn't made myself really clear ;) will edit my post

Comment: I don't know what `Item` or `item.component` or `c` or `unit_info` are, What their type are  what `c.generateUnitInfo()` returns. So your question is still unclear. But I lost my interest in this question. Good luck,

Comment: Item is the class or is it not clear to you in the declaration? But thanks anyways

Comment: @vice_versa In your question, your class declaration for `Item` has only one member, a `Dictionary<string, object>` called `components`.  But in your sample code later, you are setting a bunch of properties on `Item`, like `type` and `mixins` which you did not show earlier.  Also your code references a variable `c` which you don't show the declaration of, and a method on the `c` object called `generateUnitInfo()` which you don't show what it does.  So we have no idea what is really in your object.  Which means it is very difficult to say what the expected output is or what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Because I didn't think its relevant to my question, the main part was why I didnt get the result which i wanted with the upper part of my question, but I can edit my question so you can see what the other stuff is

Comment: I required to add [ ] in Json is it possible like `format = new ["Archive BitTorrent", "JPEG", "JPEG Thumb", "Metadata"]` using above senario.