# json string creation with c#

Tags: c#, json

I am creating a string variable to use in an rest post call and it is failing. when I debug and look at the json value I am told it is not in json format. It sure seems to be key:value pairs so I an not sure what the issue here is?

instead of double single quotes I also tried escaping the " by using \ like so (neither method is good it seems):

```
//string postData = "{\"title\":\"Change Title\",  \"description\":\"Create description\",  \"scheduledStartDate\": \"2018-12-24T11:24:48.91Z\",  \"scheduledEndDate'': ''2018-12-25T11:24:48.91Z''  }";

    string postData = @"{''changeNumberForClone'': ''C03688051'',
                        ''scheduledStartDate'': ''2017-12-24T11:24:48.91Z'',
                        ''scheduledEndDate'': ''2017-12-25T11:24:48.91Z''}";
```

[image]

Comment: You would be better off using a Dictionary or custom type, then serializing to json.

Comment: Creating the JSON by hand like this is going be very error-prone, and it won't scale at all.  Create and serialize a dictionary like Crowcoder suggested.

Comment: (Your attempt to use double quotes is broken because you incorrectly switch to double single-quotes towards the end.)

Comment: `var postData = "{\"changeNumberForClone\":\"C03688051\", \"scheduledStartDate\":\"2017-12-24T11:24:48.91Z\", \"scheduledEndDate\": \"2017-12-25T11:24:48.91Z\"}";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [NewtonSoft Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), you could use the following code to obtain a correct `json` string:

```
Dictionary<String, String> jsonDict = new Dictionary<String, String>();
jsonDict.Add("changeNumberForClone", "C03688051");
jsonDict.Add("scheduledStartDate", "2017-12-24T11:24:48.91Z");
jsonDict.Add("scheduledEndDate", "2017-12-25T11:24:48.91Z");

String postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonDict);
```

If you don't want to add a new library to your project:

```
String postData = "{\"changeNumberForClone\":\"C03688051\", \"scheduledStartDate\":\"2017-12-24T11:24:48.91Z\", \"scheduledEndDate\": \"2017-12-25T11:24:48.91Z\"}";
```

In order to produce `json` strings with multiple levels of depth using the same approach, you can use `anonymous objects` as follows:

```
var obj = new { abc = new { def = new { one="1", two="2" } } };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

or, if you prefer to use `Dictionary` instances:

```
var obj = new Dictionary<String,Object>()
{
    {
        "abc", new Dictionary<String,Object>()
        {
            {
                "def" , new Dictionary<String,Object>()
                {
                    { "one", "1" }, {"two", "2" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

the output, for both approaches, would be the following:

```
{
   "abc": {
      "def" : {
         "one": "1",
         "two": "2",
      },
   }
}
```

Comment: using this method how can you add a second level of items, lets say a server list with multiple server data points under it? in other words, is dictionary only one level deep?

Comment: Dictionary<String,String> wouldn't be enough anymore. Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808718/json-net-how-to-serialize-nested-collections... and this one too that make use of anonymous objects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529169/serialize-object-with-json-net-with-nested-dictionaries

Comment: I required to add [ ] in Json is it possible like `format = new [
       "Archive BitTorrent",
       "JPEG",
       "JPEG Thumb",
       "Metadata"
      ]` using above senario.